# Component template should contain exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are
>   using  v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
 error  in ./src/App.vue

(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
  Error compiling template:

```
 <div id="app" class="container">
     <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Vue.js 2 & Firebase Sample Application</h1>
     </div>
  </div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3>Book Lists</h3>
     </div>
     <div clas ="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                Title
              </th>
              <th>
                Author
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here's my  export default

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  firebase: {
    books: booksRef
  },
  components: {
    Hello
  }
}
```

What part should I fix to remove the error?

Comment: `</div class="panel panel-default">` is your issue. I also think you're missing another closing div.

Comment: @BillCriswell exactly. hahaha.noobie problems

Comment: in such of these situations collapse or fold all lines in editor and open them from end to start. you can see some tags with problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fixed code :

```
<div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Vue.js 2 & Firebase Sample Application</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3>Book Lists</h3>
        </div>

        <div clas ="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Title </th>
                        <th> Author</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Component template should contain exactly **one** root element.

```
<template>
    <root-element-1></root-element-1>
    <root-element-2></root-element-2>
</template>
```

this will be the fix

```
<template>
    <div>
        <root-element-1></root-element-1>
        <root-element-2></root-element-2>
    </div>
</template>
```

In your case

```
</div class="panel panel-default">
```

needs to be

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
```

> Official Documentation

On the official documentation, about [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html),
somewhat "multiple" root element could be used when using `v-if` and `v-else` combo.

```
<template v-if="true">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input placeholder="Enter your username" key="username-input">
</template>
<template v-else>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input placeholder="Enter your email address" key="email-input">
</template>
```